# How to remove the nulls that show up in the table that I created from my calculated fields

Tags: date, null, data-analysis, tableau-desktop, calculated-field

Nulls that show up in the table that I created from my calculated fields, I made calculated fields from already existing date columns called target and forecast dates. This is how the original data set looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IG4lv.png)

This is what it looks like -[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ugJCw.png)

These are my calculated fields [calc field 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAKVS.png)

[calc field 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8tmjn.png)

I need them to be next to each other based on which sites they are for.

Can someone help figure out how this is happen and how to fix it

Thanks & Regards,
Ars

Comment: In your first calc, if the milestone isn't the construction start you are returning NULL.

Comment: What does your source data look like?

Comment: It looks like the image that is hyperlinked on "this" in the end of the first para "data set looks like this"